Kernel Restarting. The kernel for ExhaustiveSearch.ipynb appears to have died. It will restart automatically
I am trying run the below code:
import mysql.connector

conn = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="root",
    password="",
    database="mock_prod")

What i am doing is try to link to my mysql which is host by xampp from the jupyter notebook, but when i run the code it pop out a message "Kernel Restarting
The kernel for ExhaustiveSearch.ipynb appears to have died. It will restart automatically."

I have started the apache and mysql in xampp control panel
The database do existed in mysql.
I used the default port which is 3306 for mysql and 80 for apache
The mysql.connector package has installed

Anyone knows how to fix this?
